# How do I mutate a given residue in a structure to a different amino acid in biopythhon?

Tags: python, biopython

I'm looking for a method to mutate a residue to a proline. However, I am having an issue finding a biopython module that can accomplish this. Is it possible in biopython?

Comment: Can you please better describe what you mean by mutate an amino acid sequence? Do you want to find one or multiple RNA or DNA sequences that result in a proline after protein synthesis or do you just want to replace a letter in the sequence stored in the biopython object? Both of these manipulations are possible with biopython.

Comment: If you want to replace an amino acid in a PDB structure object, I think that's not supported out of the box. You would have to manipulate atoms, which I understand is not what you asked for (see the biopython [docs](https://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ#what-is-a-residue-id) Other tools are probably better suited for this purpose than biopython.

Comment: @fabianegli Hi, so basically I am trying to insert a new residue into a chain/strucuture. I am currently doing chain.insert(id,residue). However, when I run the function, it inserts the residue at the incorrect location so the interactions with neighbor residues is different than expected.

Comment: An [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help. Please also explain what you would expect and how that differs from the result you get.